# JOIN table query giving weird results

Tags: sql, oracle, select, join

Table 1  -  DBT_C_INT_ACCR

```
select INT_ACC.BRCH_CODE, INT_ACC.PROD_CODE, INT_ACC.REF_ID from DBT_C_INT_ACCR INT_ACC where BRCH_CODE = 784 and PROD_CODE = 'GF' and REF_ID = 'GFE1200077';

BRCH_CODE   PROD_CODE   REF_ID  
784             GF      GFE1200077
784             GF      GFE1200077
784             GF      GFE1200077
784             GF      GFE1200077
```

---

Table 2 - dbt_c_rate_refresh

```
select INT_ACC.BRCH_CODE, INT_ACC.PROD_CODE, INT_ACC.REF_ID from dbt_c_rate_refresh INT_ACC where BRCH_CODE = 784 and PROD_CODE = 'GF' and REF_ID = 'GFE1200077';


BRCH_CODE   PROD_CODE   REF_ID  
784         GF          GFE1200077
784         GF          GFE1200077
784         GF          GFE1200077
784         GF          GFE1200077
784         GF          GFE1200077
784         GF          GFE1200077
784         GF          GFE1200077
```

---

Now when tried with below Join, it gives 28 rows instead of 4 rows. Any explanation pls?

```
select INT_ACC.ref_id, RATE_REFRESH.ref_id from DBT_C_INT_ACCR INT_ACC left OUTER JOIN dbt_c_rate_refresh RATE_REFRESH ON (INT_ACC.BRCH_CODE = RATE_REFRESH.BRCH_CODE and INT_ACC.PROD_CODE = RATE_REFRESH.PROD_CODE and INT_ACC.REF_ID = RATE_REFRESH.REF_ID)
where INT_ACC.BRCH_CODE = '784'  and INT_ACC.PROD_CODE = 'GF' and INT_ACC.REF_ID = 'GFE1200077';

REF_ID      REF_ID_1
GFE1200077  GFE1200077
GFE1200077  GFE1200077
GFE1200077  GFE1200077
GFE1200077  GFE1200077
GFE1200077  GFE1200077
GFE1200077  GFE1200077
GFE1200077  GFE1200077
GFE1200077  GFE1200077
GFE1200077  GFE1200077
GFE1200077  GFE1200077
GFE1200077  GFE1200077
GFE1200077  GFE1200077
GFE1200077  GFE1200077
GFE1200077  GFE1200077
GFE1200077  GFE1200077
GFE1200077  GFE1200077
GFE1200077  GFE1200077
GFE1200077  GFE1200077
GFE1200077  GFE1200077
GFE1200077  GFE1200077
GFE1200077  GFE1200077
GFE1200077  GFE1200077
GFE1200077  GFE1200077
GFE1200077  GFE1200077
GFE1200077  GFE1200077
GFE1200077  GFE1200077
GFE1200077  GFE1200077
GFE1200077  GFE1200077
```

Comment: It gives same no. of results for any type of join..

Comment: Which RDMS are you using... mysql or oracle? It gives multple rows in your join as you are joining on a many to many relationship.

Comment: You have 7 + 4  perfectly equal rows in your tables, so the join simply does a cartesian (7*4). Why do you expect 4?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Because you aren't joining on something unique, you are effectively doing a cartesian join (aka cross join) between the rows which have duplicate join condition values in both tables.

To demonstrate, I have mimicked your tables and added a unique identifier `rn` so that you can see what happens when you do the join:

```
with dbt_c_int_accr as (select 784 brch_code, 'GF' prod_code, 'GFE1200077' ref_id, 1 rn from dual union all
                        select 784 brch_code, 'GF' prod_code, 'GFE1200077' ref_id, 2 rn from dual union all
                        select 784 brch_code, 'GF' prod_code, 'GFE1200077' ref_id, 3 rn from dual union all
                        select 784 brch_code, 'GF' prod_code, 'GFE1200077' ref_id, 4 rn from dual),
 dbt_c_rate_refresh as (select 784 brch_code, 'GF' prod_code, 'GFE1200077' ref_id, 1 rn from dual union all
                        select 784 brch_code, 'GF' prod_code, 'GFE1200077' ref_id, 2 rn from dual union all
                        select 784 brch_code, 'GF' prod_code, 'GFE1200077' ref_id, 3 rn from dual union all
                        select 784 brch_code, 'GF' prod_code, 'GFE1200077' ref_id, 4 rn from dual union all
                        select 784 brch_code, 'GF' prod_code, 'GFE1200077' ref_id, 5 rn from dual union all
                        select 784 brch_code, 'GF' prod_code, 'GFE1200077' ref_id, 6 rn from dual union all
                        select 784 brch_code, 'GF' prod_code, 'GFE1200077' ref_id, 7 rn from dual)
-- end of mimicking your tables with data in. You wouldn't need the above subqueries, as you have the tables themselves.
-- See the SQL below:
select int_acc.ref_id,
       rate_refresh.ref_id,
       int_acc.rn,
       rate_refresh.rn
from   dbt_c_int_accr int_acc
       left outer join dbt_c_rate_refresh rate_refresh on (int_acc.brch_code = rate_refresh.brch_code
                                                           and int_acc.prod_code = rate_refresh.prod_code
                                                           and int_acc.ref_id = rate_refresh.ref_id)
where  int_acc.brch_code = '784'
and    int_acc.prod_code = 'GF'
and    int_acc.ref_id = 'GFE1200077'
order by int_acc.rn,
         rate_refresh.rn;


REF_ID     REF_ID_1           RN       RN_1
---------- ---------- ---------- ----------
GFE1200077 GFE1200077          1          1
GFE1200077 GFE1200077          1          2
GFE1200077 GFE1200077          1          3
GFE1200077 GFE1200077          1          4
GFE1200077 GFE1200077          1          5
GFE1200077 GFE1200077          1          6
GFE1200077 GFE1200077          1          7
GFE1200077 GFE1200077          2          1
GFE1200077 GFE1200077          2          2
GFE1200077 GFE1200077          2          3
GFE1200077 GFE1200077          2          4
GFE1200077 GFE1200077          2          5
GFE1200077 GFE1200077          2          6
GFE1200077 GFE1200077          2          7
GFE1200077 GFE1200077          3          1
GFE1200077 GFE1200077          3          2
GFE1200077 GFE1200077          3          3
GFE1200077 GFE1200077          3          4
GFE1200077 GFE1200077          3          5
GFE1200077 GFE1200077          3          6
GFE1200077 GFE1200077          3          7
GFE1200077 GFE1200077          4          1
GFE1200077 GFE1200077          4          2
GFE1200077 GFE1200077          4          3
GFE1200077 GFE1200077          4          4
GFE1200077 GFE1200077          4          5
GFE1200077 GFE1200077          4          6
GFE1200077 GFE1200077          4          7
```

Hopefully you can see that the row with `rn = 1` from `dbt_c_int_accr` matches to each and every single row in `dbt_c_rate_refresh`.

That's because the `brch_code`, `prod_code` and `ref_id` columns for `rn = 1` in `dbt_c_int_accr` matches to the same columns in the other table for all 7 rows - as per your join condition. The same applies for the other 3 rows in `dbt_c_int_accr`.

You get 28 rows because 4 * 7 = 28.

This isn't a weird result; it's *exactly* what you asked for with that particular join condition. If you were after different results, then you'll have to amend your join accordingly.

Comment: Thank you... could you also advise on how to get 4 expected rows in above case ?

Comment: @SnehalMasne That depends. What is the logic behind getting 4 output rows? Perhaps you don't need a join at all?

Comment: The general logic of left outer join - getting all the rows of left table and common rows of right one. The same would have happened in above example had there been no duplicates. Since there are duplicates, I am getting Cartesian result - How do I overcome that?

Comment: Why are you trying to outer join in the first place? What is the problem you're actually trying to solve? Is this a homework question, or do you really have production tables with this data in it? What is the purpose of joining the rows? Are there other columns in the tables you wish to show once you've joined the tables?

Comment: What is shown above is just a set of required columns. There are 100's of other columns present and have diff values. There is such business case which needs to deal with above scenario of joining tables and then processing other columns. Anyways, thanks a lot for your clarification :)

Comment: Ok, so is the join really on those columns, or are you missing some other columns? How do you determine which row in `dbt_c_int_accr` and which row in `dbt_c_rate_refresh` matches when they have the same join condition? If you can extend the data in your question to include some of the other columns, along with the expected output, perhaps we can help you further. Maybe you just want the first row in `dbt_c_int_accr` to match against the first row in `dbt_c_rate_refresh`, but of course, you need to define what counts as "first" in both cases. The analytic function `row_number()` may be of use.